# array_merge making new array

Tags: php, arrays, array-merge

I have 2 arrays :

`$a` and `$b`

i want to merge this arrays to `$res`

here is my code:

```
$a = array("
    [0] => Array
        (
            [0] => 45677
            [ID] => 45677
            [1] => 10
            [post_author] => 10
            [2] => 2014-02-26 19:05:59
            [post_date] => 2014-02-26 19:05:59
            [3] => 2014-02-26 14:35:59
            [post_date_gmt] => 2014-02-26 14:35:59
        )");
$b= array("
    [0] => Array
        (
            [first_image] => http://gogole.com/a.jpg
        )");


$res = array_merge($a,$b);
```

OUTPUT :

```
Array
(
    [0] => 
    [0] => Array
        (
            [0] => 45677
            [ID] => 45677
            [1] => 10
            [post_author] => 10
            [2] => 2014-02-26 19:05:59
            [post_date] => 2014-02-26 19:05:59
            [3] => 2014-02-26 14:35:59
            [post_date_gmt] => 2014-02-26 14:35:59
        )
    [1] => 
    [0] => Array
        (
            [first_image] => http://gogole.com/a.jpg
        )
)
```

it should be something like this :

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [0] => 45677
            [ID] => 45677
            [1] => 10
            [post_author] => 10
            [2] => 2014-02-26 19:05:59
            [post_date] => 2014-02-26 19:05:59
            [3] => 2014-02-26 14:35:59
            [post_date_gmt] => 2014-02-26 14:35:59
            [first_image] => http://gogole.com/a.jpg
        )
    )

)
```

what is problem ?

and how can i fix it ?

Comment: The problem is that your "arrays" are not multi-dimensional arrays. They're an array with one long string in it...!

Comment: sounds like you don't want `array_merge()` but you want [`array_push()`](http://www.php.net/array_push)

Comment: why would `$res = array_merge($a[0],$b[0]);` not be a correct option, just wondering...?

Comment: @webeno because he's not defining the multi-dimensional arrays properly, so there is only one element. You would essentially be making an array with two strings, which is not what he wants.

Comment: @echolocation I wasn't really considering his way of coding, based my answer merely on the assumption that he actually has multidimensional arrays... thanks for answering my question though!

Answer (score 4):

You're not defining the arrays correctly.  I have a feeling you used an outputted `var_dump` of someone's to define your array, but that is not for the purposes of using in code.  It is for a easily understandable array.  You could change this:

```
$b= array("
    [0] => Array
        (
            [first_image] => http://gogole.com/a.jpg
        )");
```

To this:

```
$b= array(array('first_image' => 'http://gogole.com/a.jpg'));
```

Also, you would need to do the same with the `$a` array.

---

Also, for it to function in the way that you want, you would need to use `array_merge($a[0],$b[0]);`.

Comment: it's not working , i got this error : `Notice: Use of undefined constant first_image - assumed 'first_image' `

Comment: You are using the code before my edit.  Try the edited version.

Comment: it's still giving my output and not creating new array

Comment: I would need to see how you define `$a`.

Answer (score 2):

I am not sure how you are getting that output, it looks like the result from a mysql_fetch_array() as opposed to a mysql_fetch_assoc() which it seems like you are looking for. I just did the following without issue:

```
$a = array(
  'id' => '123123',
  'author' => 'Random Author',
  'date' => '2013-01-05'
);

$b = array(
  'first_image' => 'http://gogole.com/a.jpg'
);

$res = array_merge($a, $b);

echo '<pre>';
print_r($res);
echo '</pre>';
```

Result:

```
Array
(
    [id] => 123123
    [author] => Random Author
    [date] => 2013-01-05
    [first_image] => http://gogole.com/a.jpg
)
```

Answer (score 0):

I fixed your syntax, you storage value as string
Here you have Assoc arrays.
Copy this code

```
$a = array("ID"=> 45677,
            "post_author" => 10,
            "post_date" => "2014-02-26 19:05:59",
            "post_date_gmt" => "2014-02-26 14:35:59"
        );
        $b= array("first_image" => "http://gogole.com/a.jpg");


$res = array_merge($a,$b);
var_dump($res);
```

Good Luck!

Comment: i write just simple example to explain a problem , i have many array so i must post IDs as arrays index !